# How to get 3rd-party audiobooks off an iPad?

Tags: ipad, audiobook

I have a collection of audio seminars which I loaded into Apple's Books.app so I could manage and listen to them as audiobooks. I did this long enough ago that I don't remember how I did it, or what computer I was using at the time. I've just realized that they are not syncing with any of my other devices. These were not purchased from Apple, so I can't just restore purchases on them.

- I made sure that "Books" was included in "Apps that sync with iCloud" on both devices
- I look at the "Sync audiobooks" option in Finder, but that wants to erase all of the books on the iPad (yay super useful, that)
- I checked the "Files" tab for the iPad in Finder, but Books isn't listed there
- I tried various share sheet options but it only sends the title, not the audio

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get at these files? My bad for not having them properly backed up somewhere else, of course, but at one point they were syncing from my (long gone) iTunes collection.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there isn't any readily available solution to get these off the device. So going to do it the old fashioned way: connect the iPad to some decent speakers, point a USB microphone at them and record it on my MacBook. I could probably also find a cable that would let me connect my iPad's headphone jack to the MBP as a microphone, but I already have speakers and a mic.

Going to leave this one marked as unanswered in case someone happens along with a proper solution.

Comment: afaik there's no Apple solution [as far as they're concerned, the Mac contains the master copy, phones are just slaved to that], but there are 3rd party apps that can see deeper into the pad/phone. iExplorer crops up all the time on here, also iFunBox.